# Dynamically load source in div on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am using struts 1.3 framework.
I have come across a scenario that, I have set of Struts Action URLs on JSP page.
I want to load source for all of these URLs dynamically without refreshing jsp page, and each into a separate DIV.

Any pointer will be of great use.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery and AJAX is your answer!

http://jquery.com/

(JQuery has AJAX built in FWIW)

Comment: Well, technically the webserver generates the 404, so without seeing more concrete examples of your code(s), I cannot say for certain what is being done incorrectly.

Comment: But the same URL works fine if I load it as iframe source. E.g. document.getElementById('iframe1').src=url;

Comment: Again, without seeing the specifics, I can't begin to troubleshoot why its not working.  I've used JQuery and AJAX for a long time with great success.

Comment: @suhaskhot If you're having a specific problem, please ask a follow-up question with details.